# Fedex API not returning shipping rates C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fedex

I am trying to fetch shipping rates for fedex using below API and I am using C#

https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-sg/catalog/rate/v1/docs.html

But I am getting this error, below is my full code and error.

First of all I am calling OAuth API and generating token, which I am getting successfully then I am calling API to fetch rates but still not working. So any idea on this.

Error :

```
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Layer7-API-Gateway
  Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 11:09:22 GMT
  Connection: close
  Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
  Server-Timing: edge; dur=615
  Server-Timing: origin; dur=67
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Content-Length: 182
}}
```

Full code :

```
var client = new HttpClient();

string clientid = _configuration["FedEx:ClientId"];
string clientsecret = _configuration["FedEx:SecretKey"];

var url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token";

var parametersAuth = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parametersAuth.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
parametersAuth.Add("client_id", clientid);
parametersAuth.Add("client_secret", clientsecret);

var reqAuth = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parametersAuth) };
var resAuth = await client.SendAsync(reqAuth);
var authDetailsJson = await resAuth.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // here I am getting toekn successfully.

if (resAuth.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var authDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(authDetailsJson);

    JObject objRateContent = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        AccountNumber = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Value = "My account number I am placing here"
        }),
        RequestedShipment = JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Shipper = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                Address = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    City = "Anchorage",
                    StateOrProvinceCode = "AK",
                    PostalCode = "99504",
                    CountryCode = "US"
                })
            }),
            Recipient = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                Address = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    City = "Kenai",
                    StateOrProvinceCode = "AK",
                    PostalCode = "99611",
                    CountryCode = "US"
                })
            }),
            PickupType = "CONTACT_FEDEX_TO_SCHEDULE",
            RequestedPackageLineItem = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                Weight = JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    Units = "KG",
                    Value = 25
                })
            })
        })
    });

    var input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objRateContent);

    var urlquote = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/rate/v1/rates/quotes";

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, urlquote);

    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    request.Headers.Add("X-locale", "en_US");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authDetails.access_token);

    request.Content = new StringContent(input, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Does it work if you recreate the call using the bearer token in Postman?

Comment: Have you verified you received a valid token from your first call?

Comment: Yes token is valid

Comment: There is more information needed from your side. Take @Neil advice and try the request with the token in Postman or similar application. If it fails you need to dive further into the documentation. If it succeeds your issue is within your request. Try something like Fiddler to intercept both reqeusts and compare to find the difference.

Comment: Does your token containing required scope?

Comment: 403 implies not authorized, so something is still amiss in the request somewhere.